# Android Room Database: How to query alphabetically by name?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

So I am using room database to persist users locally, now users have this entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Users{

public string name;
public string email;
@PrimaryKey
public string id;

......

}
```

I retrieve all these users with a DAO that looks like this:

```
@DAO
public interface UsersDAO{

@Query("select * from Users")
public List<Users> getAllUsers();


}
```

The above DAO will read all users in the order they were added to the database.

**Question:**

Is it possible to query users by the `name` field in `Users` entity alphabetically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ORDER BY` keyword.

```
"select * from Users ORDER BY name"
```

Comment: Thanks, so order by name will automatically know that I mean order alphabetically, even though I don't say alphabetically?

Comment: Yes. It is ascending by default. Here is the full syntax `ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;`.

Comment: You are right. It will work with numerical values too.